# What is the recommended folder structure for a Ruby command-line app with tests?

Tags: ruby, command-line, rspec, rubygems

I'm new to the Ruby development ecosystem and learning Rails in my spare time. However, I would like to build a command-line app from scratch with unit tests as a part of my learning.

What is the recommended structure for a Ruby command-line project? The one I came up with is

```
/test
  - person_test.rb
/src
  - person.rb
main.rb
Gemfile
Gemfile.lock
```

Thanks

Comment: Bundler can be used to create ruby gems [structure](https://bundler.io/guides/creating_gem.html). RubyGems also have a [tutorial](https://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/) on best practices when creating ruby applications. In short you will have a lib folder, which all your ruby files live in, a test folder for your tests, and bin folder which have the script to run your cmd application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Unit Tests for Gems

If you're using MiniTest or similar, the expected place within gem *foo* would be `foo/test`. If you're using RSpec or minitest/spec, then you'd use `foo/spec` instead.

When you generate a new gem skeleton with Bundler it provides the following defaults:

```
$ bundle gem foo; tree foo
```

> ```
> foo
> ├── Gemfile
> ├── README.md
> ├── Rakefile
> ├── bin
> │   ├── console
> │   └── setup
> ├── foo.gemspec
> ├── lib
> │   ├── foo
> │   │   └── version.rb
> │   └── foo.rb
> └── spec
>     ├── foo_spec.rb
>     └── spec_helper.rb
>
> 4 directories, 10 files
> ```

The default Rakefile is set up to run RSpec, but you can certainly implement the Rakefile's default task and your tests any way you'd like.